# Cookies not sent after a 302 redirect to a page on the same domain

Tags: http, servlets, redirect

I'm very confused by this.. My web application uses Spring Security which relies upon a JSESSIONID cookie to maintain a users session.

One of my pages does a 302 redirect to another page on the same domain, still http, not switching to https or anything fancy. For some reason the browser (Chrome in this case) does not pass the cookie with the second request and the user looses his session.

Is this the expected http behavior? I'm probably missing something..

Just to be clear, the cookie is already set before the redirect, I'm not setting the cookie in the same response as the redirect.

Comment: had the same issue. in my case it was intermittent. it would only appear in edge browser and android phone. it worked ok in chrome in the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Turns out that one has to use a 303 (see other) response when redirecting from a post request.

From RFC 2616

> 10.3.4 303 See Other
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and
>   SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method
>   exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to
>   redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a
>   substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303
>   response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
>   (redirected) request might be cacheable.

Comment: Using a 303 instead of 302 has fixed your cookie problem? Seems strange.If the cookie domain and path settings are OK a 302 should not prevent cookie usage.

Comment: My (vague) understanding is that the specification is a bit ambiguous when it comes to changing http method during a 302 redirect (post => get) and that the 303 status code was added sort out this ambiguity. I might be talking out of my ass though, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: The status code used in the (redirect) response can not possibly have anything to do with the cookie being sent by the browser in the following request, particularly if "the cookie is already set before the redirect". The request sent by the browser (as a result of the previous redirect response) is the same as any other request from the browser, so any _valid_ cookies should also be sent.

Comment: 303 didn't help in in my case with Google Chrome / Mac OS.

Comment: this was quite puzzling. i am using grails which has a redirect function. the cookie was lost during redirect. the issue occurred in edge browser and in my andrid phone. after manually setting the response code response.setStatus(303);   response.setHeader("Location", ) it worked amazingly. this was quite unexpected. thanks

Comment: I'm using go which have a http.Redirect function too, the cookie lost during redirect. I add an extra param in http.Cookie which is "Path" - the value is the path it redirect to and it works.

Answer (score 10):

It could be a bug in Chrome. See Chromium bug #[696204](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696204). In my case the workaround was changing `SameSite=Strict` to `Lax`.

Comment: Changing SameSite to lax solved the problem, but it doesn’t seem like it’s due to that bug, which was closed citing a [changed system date on the web server](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696204).

Comment: But why would it solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

302 doesn't delete any cookie, so I think you are changing the host/port or the server expires the cookie. Look at this 3 requests (before 302, 302, after 302) and search something related to Set-Cookie header with a expires value.

It could be you have a problem with the cookie path, if you set the cookie path to a something different to '/', it will be not accessible to all paths.